# proportion in counts for two factor groups using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been using this in order to get the proportion of counts for each class for two groups but am not getting the right results.

It must be the proportion of vegclas within each density and not the overall proportion of the total count.

```
veg %>%
  group_by(density,vegclas) %>%
  summarise(total.count=n(),
                 avg=total.count/count(veg)*100)
```

Result:

```
Source: local data frame [12 x 4]
Groups: density [?]

   density vegclas total.count      avg
    (fctr)  (fctr)       (int)    (chr)
1        H       1        1201 <dbl[1]>
2        H       2        1258 <dbl[1]>
3        H       3         162 <dbl[1]>
4        H       4        4745 <dbl[1]>
5        H       5        2807 <dbl[1]>
6        H       6         114 <dbl[1]>
7        L       1        1109 <dbl[1]>
8        L       2         469 <dbl[1]>
9        L       3          56 <dbl[1]>
10       L       4        1701 <dbl[1]>
11       L       5         691 <dbl[1]>
12       L       6         204 <dbl[1]>
```

Edit:

Using the length(veg) gave my this:

```
   density vegclas total.count      avg
    (fctr)  (fctr)       (int)    (dbl)
1        H       1        1201  7506.25
2        H       2        1258  7862.50
3        H       3         162  1012.50
4        H       4        4745 29656.25
5        H       5        2807 17543.75
6        H       6         114   712.50
7        L       1        1109  6931.25
8        L       2         469  2931.25
9        L       3          56   350.00
10       L       4        1701 10631.25
11       L       5         691  4318.75
12       L       6         204  1275.00
```

Comment: I'd guess it get messed up because of the `count` function. Maybe try `length(veg)` instead. Either way, we can't really reproduce this.

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: If I understand correcly what you want: As `veg` is a dataframe (or a similar 2D object) try `nrow` instead of `length`or `count`

Comment: Very close with the nrow solution. I gives me the proportion of all the rows and not within each density...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you lack a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) I use the `mtcars` dataset. To get the percentages for each level of `cyl` (`vegclas` in your case) within each level of `gear` (`density` in your case) you may do:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
    mutate(
       n.gear=n()
    ) %>%
  group_by(gear, cyl) %>% 
    summarise(
       n = n(),
       percent = n / unique(n.gear) * 100
    )
```

Note that the percentages add up to 100 in each level of gear.

```
   gear   cyl     n   percent
  (dbl) (dbl) (int)     (dbl)
1     3     4     1  6.666667
2     3     6     2 13.333333
3     3     8    12 80.000000
4     4     4     8 66.666667
5     4     6     4 33.333333
6     5     4     2 40.000000
7     5     6     1 20.000000
8     5     8     2 40.000000
```

Comment: I was thinking the wrong way around the problem. Worked like a charm :-)

Comment: can the result be combined with ggplot and facet_grid?

Comment: Thanks all for the solution